# TYPO3 FLUID two condition in one foreach?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I have in a for each two condition. How can I clear the content? Don't need two content:

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category">
    <f:if condition="{category.uid} == 2">
        <f:if condition="{newsItem.logo}">
            Logo 1
        </f:if>
    </f:if>
    <f:if condition="{category.uid} == 3">
        <f:if condition="{newsItem.logo}">
            Logo 1
        </f:if>
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

I need one condition for 2 if´s
In PHP I take a break?
Thanks

Comment: Is it own extension or existing one?

Comment: sys_cats and dont like the same output

Comment: I know which table, just asking if above view is from your own extension or some existing one (i.e. News) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to avoid 2 similar blocks of HTML then you could use f:render and f:section:

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category">
<f:if condition="{category.uid} == 2">
    <f:render section="logo" arguments="{newsItem:newsItem}" />
</f:if>
<f:if condition="{category.uid} == 3">
    <f:render section="logo" arguments="{newsItem:newsItem}" />
</f:if>
</f:for>

<f:section name="logo">
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.logo}">
            Logo 1
    </f:if>
</f:section>
```

Comment: since fluid if-viewhelper does not support logical conditions - i would say yes

Comment: i use this way, perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ViewHelpers `v:iterator.intersect` and `v:iterator.extract` from the extension `vhs`. It's not really elegant:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.categories -> v:iterator.extract(key: 'uid') -> iterator.intersect(b: '{0: 2, 1: 3}')}">
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.logo}">
        Logo 1
    </f:if>
</f:if>
```

Alternatively, you could just write your own ViewHelper, which would be only a few lines of code.

Comment: Then you could either start using it (it has not dependencies and is useful), or write your own ViewHelper.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the vhs if stack Viewhelper:

```
<v:if stack="{0: '{category.uid}', 1: '==', 2: '2', 3: 'OR', 4: '{category.uid}', 5: '==', 6: '3'}">
    <f:then>
        <f:if condition="{newsItem.logo}">
            Logo 1
        </f:if>
    </f:then>
</v:if>
```